# is super must called in order to use superclass' method for Java

Tags: java, super

```
class StackWithMin extends Stack<NodeWithMin>{

    public void push(int value){
        int newMin = Math.min(value, min());
        super.push(new NodeWithMin(value, newMin));
    }

    public int min(){
        if (this.isEmpty()){
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }else{
            return peek().min;
        }
    }
}

class NodeWithMin{
    public int value;
    public int min;
    public NodeWithMin(int v, int min){
        value=v;
        this.min=min;
    }
}
```

When I tested this class, it seems that without or with adding super. before push/peek(line 5 and line 12) produce the same result. Thus, is super necessary?

This author of this solution have super.push(), but didn't not prefix peek(), is there any reason she did that?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean.  But prefixing `super.` is necessary if you want to call the super-class method rather than the sub-class override.

Answer (score 2):

`super`is only nessesary if `StackWithMin` overrides the `push` method and you will call the `push` method from `Stack`

Comment: @Lydia Then you do not need `super`.

Comment: ...and in this case, isn't necessary because `StackWithMin` doesn't have a `push(NodeWithMin)` override, so there's no ambiguity. `StackWithMin` has `push(int)`, which is an overload, but not an override.

Comment: @Lydia so, you have your answer: no, super is not necessary. It would be if you overrode the push() method and still wanted to call the original method, defined in the superclass.